# How can I change an item in a vector?

Tags: r

```
a<- vector(length = 3)
```

This line creates a vector `a = [FALSE, FALSE, FALSE]`.
I want to change the first entry to `TRUE`.

```
a[0] = TRUE
```

Now, `a` returns `[FALSE, FALSE, FALSE]` without updating `a[0]`, contradicting what is written on the following: https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-vector-item-in-r. Is vector in R an immutable object?

Comment: In R, vectors are indexed from `1`, not `0`.  `a[0]` is not the first element of `a`.  `a[1]` is.

Comment: Don’t mix `=` and `<-`, pick one of them and stick with it. Which one you pick is irrelevant, they’re the same. But pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R counts from 1, unlike Python. Therefore, your implementation needs a minimal change for the second part

```
a <- vector(length = 3)
a[1] <- TRUE
a
```

I hope it helps. If it does, please tick this answer.

Comment: Using `T` and `F` in place of `TRUE` and `FALSE` is discouraged because they are not reserved, unlike the long words. So they can be redefined.

Comment: edited, thanks! I wrote that because this is not inside a function